# Netcat: Should I use Ctrl+C to close the connection?

Tags: windows, netcat

I've opened netcat, and I'm entering things from the keyboard. When I've finished and I want to close the connection, should I just hit "Ctrl+C"?

I want the connection to be closed "normally", but I have no idea if Ctrl+C does that, or if it closes it "abnormally", and I have no idea how else to close the connection from the keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

To close the connection press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>, which is in practice an EOF

Comment: Hm, that didn't work. Netcat didn't stop, and the connection wasn't closed. Maybe it's because I'm on Windows? Does it work for you?

Comment: Ctrl+d is the correct way to close netcat in the *Nix world. Funny it should be different on Windows, considering it is a port anyway.

Comment: I doubt it has anything to do with netcat itself, probably it's because of differences between the terminal emulators.

Comment: Doesn't work. I understand that Ctrl+C and Ctrl+D are terminal signals in Unix/Linux and netcat simply handles them on a different channel than user input. But this question is specifically about Windows that doesn't generate these signals. So another solution needs to be found.

Comment: Works fine on Linux (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS)

Answer (score 2):

This isn't specific to `netcat`, but on Windows you need  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> followed by <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to send an EOF.

This is the equivalent of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> on a *nix shell.